# Stop git from ever tracking a file that is matched in .gitignore

Tags: git

Is there a way to stop git from ever tracking a file that is in .gitignore?

If not through git is there a bash script that can be hooked in before accepting a push?

We have had the problem lately with people who are unfamiliar with git or our workflow messing things up and deleting files that should not be touched and are essential to the operation of the application. I would like to guarantee that this won't happen again.

Comment: git doesn't track files in .gitignore. Do you mean it was already tracked, and added to .gitignore later?

Comment: I don't know how it happened, possibly explicitly added.

Comment: "Is there a way to stop git from ever tracking a file that is in .gitignore?" That's essentially what the `.gitignore` file does, though it's not enforced. I can still `git add -f ignored-file`, or modify the ignores locally. Could you explain your needs a bit more?

Comment: You can make use of pre-commit or pre-recieve hooks that don't allow to add files that are there in .gitignore. Also you can make a list of "important" files which are getting "deleted oftenly" and write in hook that these cannot be deleted.

Comment: @Chris I mean disable that command or any others that might circumvent .gitignore.

Comment: @MudassirRazvi do you know of an example script or am I on my own?

Comment: @BeaverusIV No, I couldn't it on the net. however What you need to do is find the files changed in the commit and use grep to find if any of those match the ones in .gitignore. The same way you can avoid deletion aswell. It requires a bit of shell scripting and thats it. :)